# Kentico Continuous Integration - Login failed for user

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to get Kentico Continuous Integration running as a step in my CI process. However, I'm encountering the following error when my deployment script runs:

```sh
Running Kentico Continuous Integration...
Continuous Integration Console
Kentico Software
System.Exception: Login failed for user 'MACHINE-NAME\ci-runner-user'.
   at CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication.ReportApplicationError(String message)
   at CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication.Init()
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.ConsoleApp.Program.InitKenticoApplication(String webAppPhysicalPath)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.ConsoleApp.Program.Deserialize(String webAppPhysicalPath)
   at CMS.ContinuousIntegration.ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

How do I enable the local user my deployment script runs as to successfully execute `~\CMS\bin\ContintinuousIntegration.exe -r`?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that you’re using integrated security in the web.config - make sure that the user you mention has SQL access for your Kentico DB

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that. I gave the ci-runner user `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`, and `db_owner` permissions on the DB for good measure. No dice.

Comment: Not using integrated security in the connection string. Since this is a dev instance of a new site still being built, I'm just using `Trusted_Connection=True`. The IIS app pool is running as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`, but the deploy script runs under a local user

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow PowerShell ISE to run unrestricted.  To do so follow these instructions:

- Install or make sure PowerShell ISE is installed
- Run PS as Administrator
- First time only - run this command in PS ISE, "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted". It should show LocalMachine as Unrestricted. This will allow you to execute the script for CI Restore

Comment: The script is actually running fine. It `Write-Host`s out all the convenience messages I put in the deploy script, so I know that's working. It's specifically the part of the script that calls `.\CMS\bin\ContinuousIntegration.exe -r` that bombs.